# Drop down menu - multiple tabs opening with one option

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Im working with just HTML at the moment and I would like to have a drop down menu option that opens more than one tab in the brower, I have been able to open one tab in the brower with one option but I was wondering if it is posible to open more than one with one option. I look forward to hearing from you, Thank you.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
      <select name="Dropdown" id="Dropdown">
        <option value="inidivual/Mindmap.pdf" selected="selected">Mind map</option>
        <option value="inidivual/moneymatters.xlsx">Spreadsheet</option>
        <option value="#">Identity design and documents</option>
        <option value="#">Project review</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Open" onClick="window.open(Dropdown.value,'newtab'+Dropdown.value)">
    </form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _tab_ ? A tab in the browser?

Comment: Yeah sorry, only joined the other day so I'm still not used to saying proper terms for HTML and CSS coding, so multiple tabs in the browers.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple options it should be set to multiple as this,

```
<form name="form" id="form" >
  <select name="Dropdown" multiple id="Dropdown">
    <option value="http://www.google.com" selected="selected">Mind map</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Spreadsheet</option>
    <option value="http://www.sdesigns.co.in">Identity design and documents</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com">Project review</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="go_button" id= "go_button" value="Open"">
</form>
```

and use the following jquery

```
$("#go_button").click(function(){
$("#Dropdown :selected").each(function(){
       var newLink = $(this).val();
  window.open(newLink);
  });
});
```